# How to combine BindBase() with BindAllInterfaces()?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

Can we combine BindBase() with BindAllInterfaces() to some Factory  ?

```
kernel.Bind(x =>
    {
        x.FromThisAssembly()
         .SelectAllClasses()
         .WithAttribute<SomeAttribute>()
         .BindBase();
    });
```

and

```
  kernel.Bind(x =>
        {
            x.FromThisAssembly()
             .SelectAllClasses()
             .WithAttribute<SomeAttribute>()
             .BindAllInterfaces();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.BindSelection((t, baseTypes) =>
    baseTypes.Where(bt => bt.IsInterface || bt == t.BaseType))
```

Comment: Can we also add BindToSelf () ? , if for one type exist multi binding for one type --> bindtoself